# Extending tcsh completion

Tags: shell, tcsh

I must work with tcsh.
I am using an internal tool that provides basic completion for some of its commands.
I would like to extend the completion.

I mean that in future releases the default completion may evolve.

I tried something like this:
set def_cmpl = `complete tool`

```
complete tool $def_cmpl 'n/-l/(reg short long gui)/'
```

But I don't understand the result I get.
Indeed, the quotes inside `$def_cmpl` are doubled:

```
tcsh> complete tool
''n@-t@$script@'' n/-l/(reg short long gui)/'
```

I tried some tricks with echo, sed, etc. but I can't avoid those ''.

Could somebody help me?
Please don't say go on bash... The tool doesn't support it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I did not find a solution to keep the data inside the script. So, the solution was to redirect the output of the `complete` command inside a file and then to append new lines to the file.